# Unitary element in $M_2(A)$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, exact-sequence, k-theory

> Let $A$ be a unital C*-algebra and let $a∈A$ with $\|a\|≤1.$
>
> 1. Justify that $$af(a^* a) =f(aa^*)a$$ for every continuous function $f: [0,1]→ℂ.$
> 2. Use this to show that$$v:=\begin{pmatrix}a&
>      (1−aa^*)^{1/2}\\
>     −(1−a^* a)^{1/2}&
>     a^*\end{pmatrix}$$is a unitary element in $M_2(A).$
> 3. Why is $w:=\begin{pmatrix}a&(1−aa^*)^{1/2}\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$ a partial isometry?

How might one show 1., and is my theory correct for 2.?

Let's calculate v*v:

v* v = [a*, (1 - a* a)^(1/2), -(1 - aa*)^(1/2), a] * [a, (1 - aa*)^(1/2), -(1 - a* a)^(1/2), a*]
= [a* a + (1 - a* a), a*(1 - aa*)^(1/2) - (1 - a* a)^(1/2)a, -(1 - aa*)^(1/2)a* - (1 - a* a)^(1/2)a, aa* + a(1 - a* a)a*]

Notice that i have the term (1 - a^*a)^(1/2) in the second and third entries. To simplify the calculation, so i use the given property: af(a^*a) = f(aa^*)a for every continuous function f: [0,1] -> ℂ.

Setting f(t) = (1 - t)^(1/2), we have:

a(1 - a* a)^(1/2) = (1 - aa*)^(1/2)a.

Now let's substitute this into the expression for v* v:

v* v = [a* a + (1 - a* a), a*(1 - aa*)^(1/2) - (1 - a* a)^(1/2)a, -(1 - aa*)^(1/2)a* - (1 - a* a)^(1/2)a, aa* + a(1 - a* a)a*]
= [I, 0, 0, I]

Thus, we have v* v = vv* = I, which means that v is a unitary element in M_2(A).

[here V is in column bracket](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSgbt.jpg)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: No it is not hard, but it is painful. I began to format your formulas. Please edit your post to see how I did and to make the second half readable as well. https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Comment: For 1.: easy when $f$ is a monomial, then a polynomial, then (by density) any continuous function on $[0,1].$

Comment: @AnneBauval I don't understand 1. can you clarify to me why the domain of $f$ is $[0, 1]$?

Comment: @Youem because the spectrum of $a^* a$ and of $aa^*$ are contained in this interval. What don't you understand: the question or a step (and if so, which one of the 3 steps) of the proof?

Comment: @Youem , i think The main reason for choosing [0, 1] in this context is to ensure that the function f is well-behaved and bounded.

Comment: @analysislover The main reason is rather the definition of [continuous functional calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_functional_calculus). For $f(b)$ to have a meaning, $f$ must be a continuous (hence bounded) function on the (compact) spectrum of the normal element $b\in A.$

Comment: @AnneBauval it is clear!

Comment: @Anne Bauval. For 
 a polynomial it is true. I.e.
(*)=(*)⋯(*)=(*)⋯(*)=(*). can i directly do this?

Comment: @Anne Bauval thank you but can you say more about part 2 and 3. ok i will do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. A commented, this equality is straightforward for $f(x)=x^n.$ The property then extends by linearity to polynomials and [by density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem) to continuous functions on $[0,1]$ (which contains the spectra of $aa^*$ and $a^*a,$ so that both sides of the equality make sense).
2. Your proof looks fine but should stay in your post, not in an answer, and should be [formatted correctly](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation), as commented also.
3. Check that $ww^*=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}.$ So $ww^*$ is a projection hence $w$ is a [partial isometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_isometry).